# Can long-polling be achieved in Restlet by just making the thread sleep?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, comet, restlet, long-polling

When making a `GET` request for a particular resource (i.e. `ServerResource`) if I put the thread to sleep (to simulate long-polling) what would happen? Does the framework support this? From a Java EE standpoint what are the side-effects? Does it scale well with Tomcat (or any other server?)

Has any-one tried implementing long-polling using Restlet by just making the request thread sleep?

It seems restlet has no support for comet-style web applications and hence the question of such a *hack*, so to speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocking a thread is possible as long as you don't need a huge number of concurrent connections in which case this will cause a scalability issue.

In version 2.1 of the Restlet Framework edition for JavaSe, the internal non-blocking NIO connector has added such capabilities (handling any number of connections with a limited thread pool) even though it isn't fully stable and documented yet.

Comment: We do need a good deal of concurrent connections - it's an internal enterprise application but we do need to 'poll' for *updates* (similar to facebook). Is there a way you suggest it be achieved?