# Using Jetty continuations in Restlet to implement Long-Polling

Tags: jetty, comet, restlet, long-polling

I have this Restlet structure:

I instanciate a Server object:

```
server = new Server(new Context(), config.getServerProtocol(), config
                            .getServerPort());
```

Afer i instanciate a new MyApp class that extends Application:

```
app = new org.myproject.restlet.server.MyApp(
    config, server.getContext());
app.start();
```

And starts the server:

```
server.setNext(app);
server.start();
```

I haven't any Component, MyApp distribute to a Router and process the request. If at this point anybody have a comment, it will be grateful.
I'm using Restlet 2.0.14 JSE, and i link the jetty jars to use it like my http server. My server works ok, i have a javascript client that makes ajax calls, with a classical poll. But i need to implement a long-polling in the server (i discard stream and push modes for some reasons).
I'm reading about how can implement this, the first way (ugly way) could be:
- Sleeping the thread in server and resume when the server may have something. This way is discarded because it isn't scalable ([here are a post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051723/can-long-polling-be-achieved-in-restlet-by-just-making-the-thread-sleep)).
- The second way could be using the Jetty continuations api of version 7. In this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations) i can see how use the jetty comet api to suspend the request, but i dont know how apply to my restlet implementation, as stated in this [another link](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/Continuation.html), i can see:

```
Continuation continuation = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(request);
continuation.suspend();
```

But getContinuation method receives a ServletRequest object. But my request isn't a ServletRequest. Anybody knows how convert or use a ServletRequest in restlet? Probably i dont have all the concepts with the server programming.

Comment: at this point, now that servlet 3.0 has been out a while I would look for a restlet servlet that supported servlet 3.0 async operations and deploy into jetty8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't use Jetty continuations with the jetty instantied by Restlet. To implement the long-polling I forgot Restlet and implement with the java concurrency: `wait()` & `notify()` and everything is running ok.